# Add class to url with php

Tags: php

I have a database with roughly 500 cards.

They have qualities 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Each quality has different colors, in CSS I have:
`.quality0 { color: grey }`, `.quality1 { color: green }` and so on...

**I want if there's an URL on the page, like mywebsite.com/card/card_id_comes_here, then add a class called quality + print $card['quality']**
$card['quality'] is the number (0,1,2,3,4,5) from database.

I use this code on pages where I just list the cards and their names, there's no problem with this, because everything is already there:

```
<a class="quality<?php print $card['quality'] ?>" 
href="/card/<?php print $card['id']; ?>"> 
<?php print $card['name']; ?></a>
```

But if I create a new article and link to these card pages, It won't type manually to all URLs that class="quality3" or so...

**I want if I have an URL with mywebsite.com/card/id to add the class quality + print the id from database as I mentioned above.
How is this possible?**

Comment: More ofter then not, php short syntax for print can be used (e.g. `<?= $card['quality'] ?>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to retrieve the id from the url. The best way probably is to use the mod-rewrite module and retrieve the id-variable from the url via $_GET.

It is a bit tricky if you have never done it before, you better look at some examples and read a guide like this one: [Guide to mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)

edit: If you have the ID, I guess you know how to do the rest, right?